# Magento 1.9.3.2 add purchase order number to order grid

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-grid

I am using Magento 1.9.3.2 and I have got payment method to show along wits order sku's following:

https://www.atwix.com/magento/adding-sku-column-to-orders-grid/

But, I would also find it rather useful to have the purchase order number on the grid if the order was made using purchase order.

Would anyone know how l could add this field into my order grid ?

Still, looking to get this sorted and I have found this possible solution:

https://sarfarazlaghari.wordpress.com/2015/09/02/magento-adding-purchase-order-number-in-sales-order-grid/

Would this be a suitable solution or is there a better way?

Line **33** from the Atwix observer has this line:

```
 $select->joinLeft(array('payment' => $collection->getTable('sales/order_payment')), 'payment.parent_id=main_table.entity_id', array('payment_method' => 'method'));
```

If I change **'method'** to **'po_number'**  I can see the Purchase order numbers in payment method column in the grid.

> My solution so far:
>
> I have amended
> **app/code/local/Atwix/ExtendedGrid/Model/Observer.php** on line 34 so now, the function looks as such:
>
> ```
>  public function salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore($observer)
> {
>     $collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
>     $select = $collection->getSelect();
>     $select->joinLeft(array('payment' => $collection getTable('sales/order_payment')),'payment.parent_id=main_table.entity_id',array('payment_method' =>'method', 'po_number' => 'po_number'));
>     $select->join('sales_flat_order_item','`sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id',array('skus' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ", ")')));
>     $select->group('main_table.entity_id');
> }
> ```
>
> Then I updated
> **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/atwix/extendedgrid.xml** by adding:
>
> ```
>  <action method="addColumnAfter">
>             <columnId>po_number</columnId>
>             <arguments>
>                 <header>PO Number</header>
>                 <index>po_number</index>
>                 <filter_index>payment.po_number</filter_index>
>                 <type>text</type>
>             </arguments>
>             <after>payment_method</after>
>  </action>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have amended
> **app/code/local/Atwix/ExtendedGrid/Model/Observer.php** on line 34 so now, the function looks as such:
>
> ```
>  public function salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore($observer)
> {
>     $collection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
>     $select = $collection->getSelect();
>     $select->joinLeft(array('payment' => $collection getTable('sales/order_payment')),'payment.parent_id=main_table.entity_id',array('payment_method' =>'method', 'po_number' => 'po_number'));
>     $select->join('sales_flat_order_item','`sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id',array('skus' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ", ")')));
>     $select->group('main_table.entity_id');
> }
> ```
>
> Then I updated
> **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/atwix/extendedgrid.xml** by adding:
>
> ```
>  <action method="addColumnAfter">
>             <columnId>po_number</columnId>
>             <arguments>
>                 <header>PO Number</header>
>                 <index>po_number</index>
>                 <filter_index>payment.po_number</filter_index>
>                 <type>text</type>
>             </arguments>
>             <after>payment_method</after>
>  </action>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, `if the order was made using purchase order.`
So where do you persist that PO number. The link you have added here is calling PO number from payment table. If you are expecting that value then you can go ahead with the link else you'll need additional implementation.

Comment: Persist that PO number? I am using the included purchase order payment of magento. the PO number sare kept in the table sales_flat_order_payment

Comment: then pick that code, it should solve your problem.

Comment: I updated my question with my solution so far, would you say it is an suitable solution ?